# How to get distinct properties value from array?

Tags: javascript, arrays

I have this array?

```
var arr = [{id:"1",Name:"Tom"},
           {id:"2",Name:"Jon"},
           {id:"3",Name:"Tom"},
           {id:"4",Name:"Jack"}]
```

From array above I need to fecth all existing Names distinct.

```
var result = getNamesDistinct(arr);
```

The `result` should contain result is:

```
 ["Tom","Jon","Jack"];
```

My question is how to get all existing Names from arr distinct?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do it via **[Set](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Set)** object

```js
const arr = [
   { id: "1", Name: "Tom" },
   { id: "2", Name: "Jon" },
   { id: "3", Name: "Tom" },
   { id: "4", Name: "Jack" }
];

const uniqueNames = [...new Set(arr.map(item => item.Name))];

console.log(uniqueNames);
```

Or you can iterate over the array and add condition to get only unique names.

```js
const arr = [
   { id: "1", Name: "Tom" },
   { id: "2", Name: "Jon" },
   { id: "3", Name: "Tom" },
   { id: "4", Name: "Jack" }
];

const uniqueNames = arr.reduce(function(arr, item) {

   if(arr.indexOf(item.Name) === -1) {
      arr.push(item.Name);
   }

   return arr;

}, []);

console.log(uniqueNames);
```

Comment: I have syntex erroron the arrow.

Comment: Suren thanks for post.Can you provide example please?

Comment: @Michael I have updated the code

Answer (score 3):

If [**`Set`**](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Set) is available, you can simply do

```
new Set(arr.map(obj => obj.Name))
```

(pass the set to [`Array.from`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/from) if you need an array)

Answer (score 1):

you can try this

```
var array = [{
        id: "1",
        Name: "Tom"
    }, {
        id: "2",
        Name: "Jon"
    }, {
        id: "3",
        Name: "Tom"
    }, {
        id: "4",
        Name: "Jack"
    }]

    function uniqueNames(array) {
        var newArray = [];
        array.forEach((value, key) => {
            newArray.push(value.Name)
        });
        return newArray
    }
   var myNewArray =  uniqueNames(array)
```